# Abstract classes vs. templates - good practices

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style

Let's say I have got some kind of class, that represents algorithm and this algorithm requires something special from the data (eg. some member function).

In example we can do:

```
                                          <<interface>>
+------------------------+               +------------+
|       Algorithm        |    <<uses>>   |    Data    |
+------------------------+-------------->+------------+
| + doJob(inData : Data) |               | +getPixel()|
+------------------------+               +------------+
```

And we can force user of Algorithm to inherit from Data every time he wants to use class algorithm. We can also do a template:

```
template<typename T>
doJob(T&& inputData){
   //implementation
}
```

(function without class to simplify things)

And we force our client to create classes, that have methods of proper name, but we do not make him implement our abstract class (interface in different languages) (a little bit better performace maybe?)

And my question is:

Which approach is better?

- When having the choice should we implement things in a template way or abstract way in a library?
- Is there a reason for standard not to define some standard "Interfaces" like std::container or std::factory (just examples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have more than one question, so, let's answer them one by one:

> Which approach is better?

Neither is better in general. Each has is strengths and weaknesses. But you do come to an interesting point: on a more abstract level, those two are pretty much the same.

> When having the choice should we implement things in a template way or abstract way in a library?

With templates you get:

1. In general, faster execution. It can be *much* faster, 'cause a lot of inlining, and then optimization, can be done. OTOH, with an advanced de-virtualization compiler/linker and functions that can't be much inlined/optimized, you might get pretty much the same speed.
2. Slower compile times. It can be *much* slower, especially if you go the "fancy template-meta-programming" way.
3. Worse compiler errors. They can be *much* worse, especially if you go the "fancy template-meta-programming" way. When C++ gets support for concepts, one should be able to avoid this.
4. If you design it carefully, improved type-safety. OTOH, if you're not careful, you'll end up in worse duck-typing than Smalltalk. Concepts would be a tool that could help here, too.

With virtual functions / interfaces, you get:

1. De-coupled design, where, if you're careful, changes from one file won't require a re-compilation of others, and compile times can be much faster.
2. Run-time polymorphism, meaning you can dynamically load code (it ain't as easy as it sounds, but, it's possible)
3. Something that looks more familiar to someone who's experienced in OO.

> Is there a reason for standard not to define some standard "Interfaces" like std::container or std::factory (just examples)?

One could find a lot of "low-level" reasons, I guess, but the fundamental reason is performance. That is, STL was designed to be "as fast as can be", and putting some (useful) interfaces "on top if it" now is pretty-much impossible.

Comment: great answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an opinion based question. The best way to force a client to fulfill it's obligations is to make him sign a contract, that contact being an interface.

Comment: If so, why standard library or boost, which generally are considered as very advanced and cool uses templates only?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example? Where you see a potential need for an interface but it was not used.

Comment: Iterators for example does not inherit from common interface, but they could. Containers also do not inherit from a common interface.

Comment: I imagine with iterators because of pointer arithmetic being available unlike Java, .Net.

Comment: Regarding Java. Java's AbstractCollection<T> implements Iterable<T>, which has one method interator() returning Iterator<T>.